# What storage system to use for a real time messaging?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, api, mongodb, redis

I am developing a Real Time messaging application (such as WhatsApp and co) and I am facing a big question.
The application itself is not as complicated as what exists on the market. However, I am no sure what storage system I should use. I have several ideas but I don't know which one is better that the others:

- A simple mysql database with relations between messages/conversations/conversations
- A mongodb with replicate of each conversations for all users in the conversations
- A redis store with replicate conversations for all users in the conversations.

I don't know which one is better for what I want to do. If you have some advise so I can choose the right solution. (or if there is a solution I haven't listed which is even better :) )

Note : My API is developped in Ruby On Rails (if this can help make a decision)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data volume and number of read/writes should be the key factor leading you to the decision. If the data volume and number of read/write is not going to be huge you can do with mysql. I believe few TB of data with few hundreds of read/writes per minute is SQL database territory. Beyond that it is NoSQL world. However, you should be ready to deal with increased complexity of non-SQL data store design, query implementation, and achieving eventual consistency if you choose NoSQL solution. All the best!